# Snake Game in C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, snake-game

Recently, I have been trying to learn SOLID principles. I learn the best through criticism.

I made this snake game in Unity with C#, where I put my current understanding of SOLID principles to test. The game itself works wonderful, but I am trying to write better code.

**Main questions:**

1. What principles am I breaking? And how can I fix them?
2. Should I use interfaces instead of polymorphism?

**Other:**

1. Am I doing any bad practises?
2. Is my design bad?

**I don't know Unity and can't read your code**

Dont worry, I barely use Unity in this game. Everything should be understandable.

**Explaining my solution:**

My solution is to have all objects placed in positions in a "grid". Multiple objects can be at any positions. Logic is handled in `Before()`, `Next()` and `After()` in all of the objects. These are called every 0.1 seconds (or per step).

Every object is independent. There are direction objects that are placed whenever the user presses a key. When a snakepart is at the same position of this direction object, then the snakepart gets that direction. The direction obj is deleted once it no longer is at a position with a snakepart.

`IVector2` is simply a class with `int x` and `int y`. It has nothing to do with interfaces (bad naming, my bad).

**Own Comment**

The number of files is ridiculous for such a small game. And it took some time too. However, bugs were INCREDIBLE easy to find and deal with. Loved it.

If you like anything, feel free to use it. I may upload the project, if it is requested. I can also upload a video of the final project, if so desired.

**Filenames overview:**

- Game.cs: Monobehavior - Start is called once on start, Update is called every frame
- CreateGame.cs
- DeleteGame.cs
- GameOver.cs
- InputHandler.cs
- Score.cs
- Snake.cs
- ObjFactory.cs
- Direction.cs
- GameObjectInstantiator.cs

**Objs**

- Obj.cs: base class
- VisualObj.cs: Obj
- AppleObj.cs: VisualObj
- SnakePartObj.cs: VisualObj - Each individual part of the snake
- BarrierObj.cs: VisualObj - GameOver if a snakepart is at a barrier
- DirectionObj.cs: Obj - Changes the direction of `snakePartObjs`

**Other**

- DataBase.cs - Here the objects are stored in this "grid"
- MultipleValuesDictionary.cs - Used in Database

**Game.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{
    public class Game : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject sphere;

        ObjFactory factory;
        InputHandler input;
        Snake snake;
        CreateGame createGame;
        GameOver gameOver;
        Score score;

        Direction inputDirection = new Direction();

        float timer = 1.0f;

        public void Start()
        {
            factory = new ObjFactory(sphere);
            input = new InputHandler();
            score = new Score();
            snake = new Snake(factory,score);
            createGame = new CreateGame();
            createGame.Create(snake, factory);
            gameOver = new GameOver(createGame, factory, snake);
            snake.InjectGameOver(gameOver);

        }

        public void Update()
        {
            timer -= Time.deltaTime;
            input.HandleArrows(inputDirection);
            if (timer < 0)
            {
                input.UseInput(factory, snake, inputDirection);
                timer = 0.1f;
                snake.Before();
                factory.CallAllBefore();
                factory.CallAllNext();
                factory.CallAllAfter();

                Debug.Log("The Current Score Is: " + score.GetScore().ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CreateGame.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Misc;
namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{
    public class CreateGame
    {

        public void Create(Snake snake, ObjFactory factory)
        {
            snake.CreateSnake(new IVector2(20,20),3);
            CreateEdgeBarriers(factory, 30, 30);
            //Five apples for fun
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
                factory.CreateVisualObject<AppleObj>(new IVector2(Random.Range(1, 29), Random.Range(1, 29)), new Color(1, 0, 0, 1));
        }

        public void CreateEdgeBarriers(ObjFactory factory,int xSize, int ySize)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < ySize; y++)
                {
                    if (x == 0 || y == 0 || x == (xSize-1) || y == (ySize-1))
                        factory.CreateVisualObject<BarrierObj>(new IVector2(x, y), new Color(0,0,0,0));
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**DeleteGame.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{
    public class DeleteGame 
    {

        public void Delete(ObjFactory factory)
        {
            factory.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

**GameOver.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{
    public class GameOver 
    {
        CreateGame createGame;
        DeleteGame deleteGame;
        ObjFactory factory;
        Snake snake;
        public GameOver(CreateGame createGame, ObjFactory factory, Snake snake)
        {
            this.snake = snake;
            this.factory = factory;
            this.createGame = createGame;
            deleteGame = new DeleteGame();
        }

        public void ResetGame()
        {
            deleteGame.Delete(factory);
            createGame.Create(snake, factory);
        }
    }
}
```

**InputHandler.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{
    public class InputHandler
    {
        public void HandleArrows(Direction dir)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            {
                dir.direction = Direction.names.Up;
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            {
                dir.direction = Direction.names.Down;
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                dir.direction = Direction.names.Left;
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                dir.direction = Direction.names.Right;
            }
        }

        public void UseInput(ObjFactory factory,Snake snake, Direction dir)
        {
            if (dir.direction == Direction.names.None)
                return;

            //Dont use oppisite input
            if (snake.GetHeadDirection().IsOppisiteDirection(dir.direction))
            {
                return;
            }

            DirectionObj o = (DirectionObj)factory.CreateObject<DirectionObj>(snake.GetHeadPos());
            o.dir.direction = dir.direction;



            dir.direction = Direction.names.None;
        }

    }
}
```

**Score.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{
    public class Score
    {
        int score = 0;
        public int GetScore() { return score; }
        public void AddPoint() { score++; }
        public void ResetScore() { score = 0; }
    }
}
```

**Snake.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Misc;
namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{
    public class Snake 
    {
        SnakePartObj head;
        SnakePartObj lastPart;
        IVector2 lastPositionOfLastPart;
        Direction.names lastDirOfLastPart;
        ObjFactory objectfactory;
        Color headColor;
        Color snakeColor;
        GameOver gameOver;
        Score score;

        public Snake(ObjFactory factory,Score score)
        {
            objectfactory = factory;
            headColor = new Color(0, 1, 0, 1);
            snakeColor = new Color(0, 0.5f, 0, 1);
            this.score = score;
        }

        public void CreateSnake(IVector2 headPos, int NumbOfParts)
        {
            head = CreateSnakeObj(headPos, headColor);

            IVector2 pos = headPos;
            pos.y--;
            for(int y = 1; y < (NumbOfParts-1); y++)
            {
                CreateSnakeObj(pos, snakeColor);
                pos.y--;
            }

            lastPart = CreateSnakeObj(pos, snakeColor);
        }

        SnakePartObj CreateSnakeObj(IVector2 pos, Color col)
        {
            SnakePartObj obj = objectfactory.CreateVisualObject<SnakePartObj>(pos, col);
            obj.InstallSnakePart(this);
            return obj;
        }

        //Skeptical on this, breaks ISP?
        public void GameOver()
        {
            score.ResetScore();
            gameOver.ResetGame();
        }

        public void InjectGameOver(GameOver gameOver)
        {
            this.gameOver = gameOver;
        }

        public void CreateNewPart()
        {
            score.AddPoint();

            lastPart = CreateSnakeObj(lastPositionOfLastPart, snakeColor);
            lastPart.dir.direction = lastDirOfLastPart;

        }

        public void Before()
        {
            lastPositionOfLastPart = lastPart.position;
            lastDirOfLastPart = lastPart.dir.direction;
        }

        public IVector2 GetHeadPos()
        {
            return head.position;
        }

        public Direction GetHeadDirection()
        {
            return head.dir;
        }




    }
}
```

**ObjFactory.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Misc;
namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{
    public class ObjFactory
    {
        GameObjectInstantiator instantiator;

        //Hold all of the positions of all objects, and the objects themselves
        DataBase<IVector2, Obj> objectDatabase;
        public ObjFactory(GameObject prefab)
        {
            instantiator = new GameObjectInstantiator(prefab);
            objectDatabase = new DataBase<IVector2, Obj>();
        }

        //Create object of type Obj and install
        public T CreateObject<T>(IVector2 position) where T : Obj, new()
        {
            T obj = new T();
            obj.Install(position);
            InsertObject(position, obj);
            return obj;
        }

        //Create object of Type ObjVisual and install
        public T CreateVisualObject<T>(IVector2 position, Color color) where T : VisualObj, new()
        {
            T obj = new T();
            obj.InstallVisual(instantiator.CreateInstance(), color);
            obj.Install(position);
            InsertObject(position, obj);
            return obj;
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            foreach (var o in objectDatabase.GetAllObjects().ToList())
            {
                o.DestroyThis(objectDatabase);
            }
            objectDatabase = new DataBase<IVector2, Obj>();
        }

        void InsertObject(IVector2 position, Obj o)
        {
            objectDatabase.AddEntry(position, o);
        }


        //Better way of doing these three functions?
        public void CallAllNext()
        {
            foreach (var o in objectDatabase.GetAllObjects().ToList())
            {
                o.Next(objectDatabase);
            }
        }

        public void CallAllAfter()
        {
            foreach (var o in objectDatabase.GetAllObjects().ToList())
            {
                o.After(objectDatabase);
            }
        }
        public void CallAllBefore()
        {
            foreach (var o in objectDatabase.GetAllObjects().ToList())
            {
                o.Before(objectDatabase);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Direction.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Misc;
namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{
    public class Direction
    {
        public enum names { Left, Right, Up, Down, None }
        public names direction { get; set; }

        public IVector2 GetVector()
        {
            switch (direction)
            {
                case names.Left:
                    return new IVector2(-1, 0);

                case names.Right:
                    return new IVector2(1, 0);
                case names.Up:
                    return new IVector2(0, 1);
                case names.Down:
                    return new IVector2(0, -1);
            }
            return new IVector2(0, 0);
        }

        public bool IsOppisiteDirection(names dir)
        {
            if(dir == names.Up && direction == names.Down)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (dir == names.Down && direction == names.Up)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (dir == names.Left && direction == names.Right)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (dir == names.Right && direction == names.Left)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**GameObjectInstantiator**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;

namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{
    class GameObjectInstantiator
    {
        GameObject prefab;
        public GameObjectInstantiator(GameObject prefab)
        {
            this.prefab = prefab;
        }
        public GameObject CreateInstance()
        {
            return (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(prefab);
        }
    }
}
```

**Obj classes**

**Obj.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Misc;
namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{

    //Should i use interfaces instead? Combined? Or not?
    public class Obj
    {
        public IVector2 position { get; private set; }


        public Obj()
        {

        }
        public virtual void Install(IVector2 position)
        {
            SetPosition(position);
        }
        public virtual void Next(DataBase<IVector2,Obj> objects) {

        }

        public virtual void After(DataBase<IVector2, Obj> objects) { }
        public virtual void Before(DataBase<IVector2, Obj> objects) { }

        public void Move(DataBase<IVector2,Obj> objects, IVector2 newPos)
        {
            newPos += position;
            objects.MoveEntry(position, newPos, this);
            SetPosition(newPos);
        }

        public void Replace(DataBase<IVector2, Obj> objects, IVector2 newPos)
        {
            objects.MoveEntry(position, newPos, this);
            SetPosition(newPos);
        }

        protected virtual void SetPosition(IVector2 pos)
        {
            position = pos;

        }

        public virtual void DestroyThis(DataBase<IVector2, Obj> objects)
        {
            objects.RemoveEntry(position,this);
        }



    }
}
```

**VisualObj.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Misc;
namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{
    public class VisualObj : Obj
    {
        GameObject instance;



        protected override void SetPosition(IVector2 pos)
        {

            base.SetPosition(pos);
            instance.transform.position = new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, 0);
        }

        public void InstallVisual(GameObject instance, Color color)
        {
            this.instance = instance;
            //Just setting the color of the visual object
            instance.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = color;
        }

        public override void DestroyThis(DataBase<IVector2, Obj> objects)
        {
            GameObject.Destroy(instance);
            base.DestroyThis(objects);
        }
    }
}
```

**AppleObj.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Misc;
namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{
    public class AppleObj : VisualObj
    {
        public AppleObj() : base()
        {
        }

        public override void Next(DataBase<IVector2, Obj> objects)
        {

            SnakePartObj snakePart = objects.GetObjectOfType<SnakePartObj>(position);

            //If there is a snake part at the apples position, then make the snake longer and place the apple in another position
            if(snakePart != null)
            {
                snakePart.GetSnake().CreateNewPart();
                Replace(objects, RandomPos());
            }
        }

        IVector2 RandomPos()
        {
            return new IVector2(UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 27), UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 27));
        }
    }
}
```

**SnakePartObj.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Misc;
namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{
    public class SnakePartObj : VisualObj
    {

        public Direction dir { get; set; }
        Direction directionChange = new Direction();
        Snake snake;
        public SnakePartObj() : base()
        {
            dir = new Direction();
            dir.direction = Direction.names.Up;
            directionChange.direction = Direction.names.Up;
        }

        public override void Next(DataBase<IVector2, Obj> objects)
        {
            base.Next(objects);
            Move(objects, dir.GetVector());
        }
        public override void After(DataBase<IVector2, Obj> objects)
        {


            var snakePartsAtPos = objects.GetObjectsOfType<SnakePartObj>(position);
            //There can only be maxinum one snake part at a position at all times
            if(snakePartsAtPos != null)
            if(snakePartsAtPos.Count > 1)
            {
                snake.GameOver();
            }
        }

        //Is this bad practice?
        public Snake GetSnake()
        {
            return snake;
        }

        public void InstallSnakePart(Snake snake)
        {
            this.snake = snake;
        }
    }
}
```

**BarrierObj.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Misc;
namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{
    public class BarrierObj : VisualObj
    {
        public BarrierObj() : base()
        {
        }


        public override void After(DataBase<IVector2, Obj> objects)
        {

            SnakePartObj snakePart = (SnakePartObj)objects.GetObjectOfType<SnakePartObj>(position);
            if (snakePart != null)
            {
                snakePart.GetSnake().GameOver();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DirectionObj.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Misc;
namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{
    public class DirectionObj : Obj
    {
        public Direction dir { get; set; }
        public DirectionObj() : base()
        {
            dir = new Direction();
            dir.direction = Direction.names.Up;
        }
        public Direction.names GetDirection() { return dir.direction; }

        public override void Before(DataBase<IVector2, Obj> objects)
        {
            base.Before(objects);

            SnakePartObj snakeObjAtPos = objects.GetObjectOfType<SnakePartObj>(position);

            //Change the direction of the snake part if it is on this directionObj
            ChangeSnakeDirection(snakeObjAtPos);
            //If there are no snake parts in this position, then delete this
            if (snakeObjAtPos == null)
                this.DestroyThis(objects);


        }

        void ChangeSnakeDirection(SnakePartObj part)
        {
            if (part == null)
                return;
            part.dir.direction = dir.direction;
        }

    }
}
```

**Other**

**DataBase.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using System;

namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{
    public class DataBase <key,obj>
    {
        MultipleValuesDictionary<key,obj> objects = new MultipleValuesDictionary<key, obj>();
        HashSet<obj> objectsHash = new HashSet<obj>();

        public void AddEntry(key key, obj obj)
        {
            objects.AddEntry(key, obj);
            objectsHash.Add(obj);
        }

        public void RemoveEntry(key key, obj obj)
        {
            objects.RemoveEntry(key, obj);
            objectsHash.Remove(obj);
        }

        public void RemoveEntry(key key)
        {
            HashSet<obj> values = objects.GetValues(key);
            foreach(var val in values)
            {
                objectsHash.Remove(val);
            }

            objects.RemoveEntry(key);

        }

        public void MoveEntry(key oldKey,key newKey, obj obj)
        {
            RemoveEntry(oldKey, obj);
            AddEntry(newKey, obj);
        }

        public Dictionary<key,HashSet<obj>> GetAllEntries()
        {
            return objects.GetDictionary();
        }

        public HashSet<obj> GetAllObjects()
        {
            return objectsHash;
        }


        public T GetObjectOfType<T>(key k) where T : obj
        {
            var objs = GetObjectsOfType<T>(k);
            if (objs == null)
                return default(T);
            if (objs.Count == 0)
                return default(T);

            return (T)objs[0];

        }

        public List<obj> GetObjectsOfType<T>(key k) where T : obj
        {
            HashSet<obj> objs = objects.GetValues(k);
            if (objs == null)
                return null;

            return objs.Where(o => (o.GetType() == typeof(T))).ToList();

        }

        public List<obj> GetObjectsOfType<T>() where T: obj
        {
            return objectsHash.Where(o => (o.GetType() == typeof(T))).ToList();
        }


    }
}
```

**MultipleValuesDictionary.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
namespace SnakeGameSOLID
{
    //Solution to having multiple values in a dictionary
    public class MultipleValuesDictionary<key, value>
    {
        Dictionary<key, HashSet<value>> dictionary = new Dictionary<key, HashSet<value>>();

        public void AddEntry(key k, value v)
        {
            HashSet<value> values;
            if (dictionary.TryGetValue(k, out values))
            {
                if (values.Contains(v))
                {
                    //Exception?
                    return;
                }
                values.Add(v);
                return;

            }
            values = new HashSet<value>();

            values.Add(v);
            dictionary.Add(k, values);
        }

        public void RemoveEntry(key k)
        {
            dictionary.Remove(k);
        }

        public void RemoveEntry(key k, value val)
        {
            HashSet<value> values = GetValues(k);
            values.Remove(val);
        }

        public Dictionary<key,HashSet<value>> GetDictionary()
        {
            return dictionary;
        }
        public HashSet<value> GetValues(key k)
        {

            HashSet<value> values;
            dictionary.TryGetValue(k, out values);
            return values;
        }

        //Gets all values of a specific type at a position
        public List<value> GetValuesOfTypeAtKey<T>(key k) where T : value
        {
            HashSet<value> values = GetValues(k);
            return values.Where(o => (o.GetType() == typeof(T))).ToList();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Too many classes for my taste. I have some doubts if e.g. `Direction` really deserves to be it's own class. Also functional classes like `CreateGame`, `DeleteGame` seem to be better actions (functions) in a single class called `Game`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Completely understand. However could it be useful for bigger projects?

Comment: Too much code for me to read through, but get rid of all the "obj" prefixes/suffixes - everything is an object, that goes without saying; you don't need to include that text in your names.

Comment: Do we really need 100 lines of "explanation" before we reach the first bit of actual code?

Comment: @eurotrash In my head it makes it easier to see what the base class is to the class by just looking at the name. But i should probably just have a map called "Objects" and have all obj inherited files in that map.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Probably dont need that. However, I find it more clean.

Comment: @Vermacian55 That's ok, except your base class shouldn't be named "object", "obj", or anything of the sort. Unless this is some weird Unity behaviour imposed on you, give it a proper name!

Comment: @Vermacian55 I find your question is ok and there is not too much introduction, on the contrary, a good overview of what's coming. True, there is a lot of code but I saw longer explanations and they were ok too.

Comment: @eurotrash Haha yes. It got nothing to do with Unity. Just my bad naming and fantasy. Is "GameObject" a better name? If not i have no clue what i should name the class haha.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I agree, those classes do not really deserve to be it. I was in doubt when i wrote them haha.

Comment: This isn't related to SOLID, but for `CreateEdgeBarriers`, instead of looping through every position on the grid to find the edges I think it would be better if you looped through each edge instead

Comment: There are 17 classes and 600 lines of code. I'd say this time it might really be too much. I'd be probably better to ask smaller questions about snake design or scoring system etc.

Comment: @Bethan True, that is better.

Comment: @t3chb0t hahah, completely understandable. Not forcing anyone to go through my code. I just hope that someone will. And still, everything helps. But atleast, in the future at a job interview, i can say that i made the snake game in just 600 lines or more :).

Comment: The code smell here is "design pattern run amok". Slavish adherence to a pattern, no matter how useful, tends to undermine the value of that pattern. You've got Class Overflow, it reminds me of [FizzBuzz Enterprise Edition](https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition). Don't let readability and YAGNI go out the window.

Comment: @CodyGray If only there weren't so many projects just like that but not intended to be ironic :(

Comment: Unity -- SOLID principles. You can pick only one, pick wisely.

Comment: Can you add a youtube video of the gameplay?

Comment: @CodyGray That FizzBuzz project was amazing, i understand what you mean.

Comment: @denis I disagree. Unity is so open that you can decide to ignore a lot of its structor. However, it may not be the wisest thing to do.

Comment: @KorayTugay Uploading a video to this link now (Done in like 10 min): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7O2xdUdTEY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @Vermacian55 Of course you can, but that's not how it should work. If you are using Unity use it the way it's meant to be used.

Comment: *too many classes*   is an observation not a diagnosis. I've seen the "too many classes" critique of actually good class designs. There are not "too many" classes in these cases. But here the classes have related functionality spread all over the place. There is poor cohesion within and across all the classes; so we say the classes are "incoherent." Cohesion is the quality of being logical, consistent and forming a unified whole.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just a few remarks. Reviewing bottom-up.

---

> ```
> public class MultipleValuesDictionary<key, value>
> ```

Don't name classes dictionary if they aren't one (implementing the `IDictionary<,>` interface). It's confusing.

You can derive a type from the dictionary instead of implementing only parts of it and inventing new vocabulary for it.

Don't come up with new generic parameters names. The conventions is to start the names with the uppercase letter `T`.

You could simply define it as:

```
public class MultipleValuesDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, HashSet<TValue>> { }
```

---

> ```
> public List<value> GetValuesOfTypeAtKey<T>(key k) where T : value
> {
>     HashSet<value> values = GetValues(k);
>     return values.Where(o => (o.GetType() == typeof(T))).ToList();
> }
> ```

No dictionary should have such method. It's a special case and you could easily get what you need with the `OfType<T>` extension:

```
 var results = multipleValueDictionary[key].OfType<MyType>().ToList();
```

---

> ```
> public class DataBase <key,obj>
> ```

This is an interesting class with an even more interesing naming convention:

> ```
> public void AddEntry(key key, obj obj)
> ```

Don't! Use `TKey` and  `TValue`.

The private `objectsHash` doesn't seem like it was necessary. The only place you use it for is

> ```
> public HashSet<obj> GetAllObjects()
> {
>     return objectsHash;
> }
> ```

where you could simply use `SelectMany`

```
 dictionary.Values.SelectMany(x => x)
```

---

> ```
> public class DirectionObj : Obj
> ```

Everything seems to be either an `Obj` or have the suffix `-Obj`. Calling everything `obj` in an OO language is like you ware calling every-thing a thing. No one would understand you.

---

> ```
> public Direction dir { get; set; }
> ```

Property names -> PascalCase. No abbreviations.

---

> ```
> dir.direction = Direction.names.Up;
> ```

The code lacks consistency but the `Obj` suffix :-)

Comment: Excellent! Bunch of things i did not know! Thank you. And .OfType seems really handy. Obj suffix <3

Answer (score 14):

I sense that you think too much about SOLID, padawon. You need to think about what the game IS, and the things that ARE. Objects do things. What they do defines what they are. Properties capture the state of a thing as it does stuff. Leave the search for the unified field theory of object oriented design for later.

Obsesssing over Open/Close results in one-method classes.

Single Responsibility is THE force w/in the SOLID universe. Your midiclorians are too low, padawon.

What, in all the universe, is not an object? To name a thing "obj" (or xxxObj)  is to deny its purpose, padawon.

Send Obj.cs to CERN, for you have discovered the one, fundamental particle that underlies the fabric of the universe. It is an amorphous abstraction  that informs all entities derived therefrom that [they have no purpose](https://youtu.be/yJJA6WRpvlg?t=107); that each obj is a distinction without a difference.

The secret is, Mr. Anderson, that there is no spoon - or Apple, or Barrier, or anything; not in this Snake Game corner of the universe. There is not a single coherent class here.

**Edit - comment copied from below**

> " what should i do about the obj situasjon? Are you calling for a rename or that the design is flawed?" The naming is a hint of a possibly flawed design. It suggests to me you're thinking in quantum particle terms, not "snake game" terms. I suggest this is where the SRP failure begins. Carefully talk your way through an explanation of the game, identifying the parts, what each part does, and how they interact. As a repetitive process you will identify specific parts and general parts, and their relationships

**End Edit**

Comment: I give you +1 for the funny story and I think he's called padawan.

Comment: I talk w/ a southern accent sometimes.

Comment: Hahahaha great. Master, i still got a lot to learn. When you say "Your midiclorians are too low", do you mean that i am not fulfilling SRP? Also, what should i do about the obj situasjon? Are you calling for a rename or that the design is flawed? If it is flawed how could i fix it? if i rename it to "DataBaseObject", it would not make a difference would it?

Comment: Oh of course. I can just do DataBase<IVector2, object> instead of DataBase<IVector2, Obj>. lol.

Comment: *"do you mean that i am not fulfilling SRP?"*  Awareness is the first step to controlling THE force, padawon. IMO, SRP is hands-down most important of SOLID; but not easy to master. One must think concretely and abstractly simultaneously. Concretely first, abstractly second. This code feels like that is reversed. In trying to bake in OO flavor first, we are not code(ify)ing coherent "problem space" concepts but ripping them apart for the sake of "OO recipies."  You have pureed your ingredients.

Comment: *" what should i do about the obj situasjon? Are you calling for a rename or that the design is flawed?"*  The naming is a hint of a possibly flawed design. It suggests to me you're thinking in quantum particle terms, not "snake game" terms. I suggest this is where the SRP failure begins. Carefully talk your way through an explanation of the game, identifying the parts, what each part does, and how they interact. As a repetitive process you will identify specific parts and general parts, and their relationships.

Comment: @radarbob Thanks man! Just the advice i needed!

Answer (score 10):

Beyond the SOLID principles, think about your classes and methods. Classes/objects are things that exist, methods are things they do. So when naming them, class names should be nouns, methods should be verbs. If you find yourself naming your classes after verbs, it indicates that you aren't thinking through what those classes are actually for.

As such, I have trouble with your CreateGame, DeleteGame, and GameOver classes. Creating and deleting is something you do with the Game object, not things that can exist by themselves. Whatever these do should be methods in the Game class, not classes unto themselves. Reading the code, I'm having trouble following what you are trying to do in instantiating CreateGame and DeleteGame objects. I think if you rethink these classes into methods you perform on the Game class you will also find your code to become simpler. Taken further, a method called Create probably isn't necessary for the Game class. Creating an instance of the class is what the constructor is for.

GameOver is a little different in that the name doesn't really describe a noun or a verb, but rather a state of the Game (that is, the state of a game that has ended). Consider rewriting this as a method on the Game class called End, or, since it appears all this is doing is deleting the game if I am reading your code right, just incorporate its logic into the Game.Delete method. Your ResetGame method you have in GamOver is, again, an action you are performing on Game, and should be part of the Game class.

Good general rule:

Class = noun (something that IS)

Method = verb (something a class DOES)

Another trick you can use is say to yourself what you are trying to accomplish with a sentence like "I need to {method} the {class/object}" (e.g. "I need to Start the Game" or "I need to Remove the SnakePart"). Then you know if that is a method that needs to be on that class. Similarly, you can apply this to code you have already written to see if it makes sense. If you end up with sentences that don't make sense like "I need to ResetGame the GameOver", it is likely something went askew and it is a good time to revise what you were trying to do there.

Comment: Yeah, the 'CreateGame' game and such classes is a clear mistake on my side. Thanks for the trick! I can see it being useful.

Answer (score 5):

**Overall design**

*First a summary of your design:*

The `Game` class initializes the game and runs the main game loop (`Update`). Every step, it applies user input and updates all game objects (by calling their `Before`, `Next` and `After` methods).

Game objects (the `ApplyObj`, `BarrierObj`, `SnakePartObj` and `DirectionObj` classes) are positioned on a 2D grid (represented by a `DataBase<IVector2, Obj>` instance).

The player controls a snake (the `Snake` class) that consists of multiple parts (`SnakePartObj`). When an arrow key press is handled, an invisible direction marker is placed on the grid. This marker tells snake parts in which direction they should move next. This prevents parts from becoming disconnected.

Apples check every step whether they're colliding with a snake part. If so, they tell the snake to increment its length (which increases the players score) and they'll move to a random new location.

Barriers also check every step whether they're colloding with a snake part. If so, they trigger a game-over.

**Overall design observations**

A few things stand out in the above summary:

- the direction markers
- apples and barriers are constantly checking for snake parts
- the `Before`/`Next`/`After` methods
- an odd database class

Keeping the snake together could be solved more elegantly. For example by removing the tail part and adding a new head part, so other parts don't need to move at all (when the snake grows you simply don't remove the tail). Or by giving each part a reference to the next part, so they don't need direction markers to tell them where to move next.

Why do apples and barriers need to check for snake parts all the time? Collisions always happen with the snake head, so it's sensible to only let the snake (head) check for collisions instead. Bytheway, does your code take into account that the snake may hit itself?

Having 3 different update methods indicates that you were running into order problems. With the above two changes, you likely don't need these 3 methods anymore. In fact, a single `Snake.Update` call per step should be sufficient - all other game objects are passive anyway.

`DataBase<key, obj>` implies persistent storage, but it's actually used to represent a 2D grid that contains game objects. `Grid` (or `Level`, `Map`, `Environment`) would be a more descriptive name. The class is also only used with `IVector2` as key and `Obj` as value (obj), and its method names heavily imply 2D movement, so there is no reason to make it generic. YAGNI: 'you ain't gonna need it'.

**Class design**

When we look further into the code, we'll see that game objects (`Obj`) are created (and also updated) via a factory (`ObjFactory`), which also registers them in the game grid (`DataBase<IVector2, Obj>`). There's an additional factory for creating visual parts (`GameObjectInstantiator`).

The `DataBase<key, obj>` class is gives you access to all game objects, and provides fast spatial lookup for collision checks. It's using a `MultipleValuesDictionary<key, value>` class internally.

There are also several game-state related classes, such as `CreateGame`, `DeleteGame` and `GameOver`. `CreateGame` initializes the player snake and populates the game grid with barriers and apples, while `DeleteGame` erases the game grid, and `GameOver` uses the other two to restart the game.

Then there are the `InputHandler`, `Score`, `Direction` and `IVector2` classes - utilities, mostly. `InputHandler` checks for arrow key presses and returns an appropriate direction, `Score` keeps track of the score, `Direction` is used in various places as movement direction (up, down, left or right) and `IVector2` stores a 2D coordinate.

**Class design observations**

If we inspect the code, we'll note several things:

- `ObjFactory` mixes object creation with updating (game logic)
- a custom (semi-)dictionary class
- the game grid must be kept up to date whenever an `Obj` is moved
- some game-related functionality has been implemented with classes instead of methods
- `Direction` is oddly designed

`ObjFactory` has too many responsibilities. Those `CallAll*` methods do not belong there. It's also doing very little, so I'm not really convinced that a factory is adding much value here. One disadvantage of this design is that it uses a `new()` constraint, so you can't use constructors to enforce proper initialization (`SnakePartObj` is not properly initialized until you call `InstallSnakePart`, but the factory doesn't do that for you).

There's no need for `MultipleValuesDictionary<key, value>` - it's essentially just a `Dictionary<IVector2, HashSet<Obj>>`. If that's too inconvenient to use then a few (extension) helper methods should be sufficient. You could also use a 2D array of `HashSet<Obj>`. Actually, without direction markers you don't need to support multiple objects per cell, so a 2D array of `Obj` is sufficient.

Keeping object positions in sync with the game grid obviously complicates things. It may be easier to just keep a list of game objects - there aren't that many and you only need to check for collisions once, for the snake's head, so it's unlikely that you'll run into performance problems. Or, with a different snake movement strategy (removing/adding parts instead of moving them) you don't need any movement support at all. Alternately, you could perform all movement via the grid directly, so game objects don't need those methods that require a game grid reference.

Others have already commented on your `CreateGame`, `DeleteGame` and `GameOver` classes: those should be methods in `Game`.

`Direction` is a mutable class that holds a `names` enum, and it contains some utility methods. Its mutable nature allows some rather unintuitive code: `InputHandler.HandleArrows` returns a direction by mutating its `Direction` argument. It would be much easier to understand (and harder to misuse) when `Direction` was an enum itself, and `InputHandler.HandleArrows` would just return a `Direction` (enum). You may want to read up on '(data) encapsulation'.

**Conclusion**

There's more to be said about the actual low-level code itself (adhering to standard C# naming conventions, using more descriptive method and class names, not hard-coding values, various other low-level improvements), but I feel this review is long enough as it is.

All in all, I think your code is overly complicated for what it does. SOLID is good and all, but don't forget KISS: 'keep it simple, stupid'. :)

Comment: The overall design summary is on point. "_Bytheway, does your code take into account that the snake may hit itself?_", yes. In SnakePartObj.cs After function, it checks if there are more than one snakePartObj at the same position. If so then it is gameover. When a snake "bites" itself, it will cause two snakeparts to be at the same position. And yes, i was running into order problems, which your examples fix. I felt like my design gave a lot of freedom, but then again as you said "YAGNI".

Comment: Dont quite get what you mean by "_the game grid must be kept up to date whenever an Obj is moved_", the grid is a class, and therefore a reference right? So it will be kept up to date automaticly, right?

Comment: "_Keeping object positions in sync with the game grid obviously complicates things. It may be easier to just keep a list of game objects_". I made the code in such a way as if it was a big project, to test the waters. But then again "YAGNI"

Comment: "_ One disadvantage of this design is that it uses a new() constraint, so you can't use constructors to enforce proper initialization (SnakePartObj is not properly initialized until you call InstallSnakePart, but the factory doesn't do that for you)._", do you know a way to get around that?

Comment: And yes indeed KISS. Thanks! This cleared up a ton of things for me!